# Electrically charging edges in a force-based graph drawing algorithm?

Tags: language-agnostic, physics, graph-algorithm, graph-drawing

I'm attempting to write a short mini-program in Python that plays around with [force-based algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-based_algorithms_%28graph_drawing%29) for graph drawing.

I'm trying to minimize the number of times lines intersect.  Wikipedia suggests giving the lines an electrical charge so that they repel each other.  I asked my physics teacher how I might simulate this, and she mentioned using calculus with Coulomb's Law, but I'm uncertain how to start.

Could somebody give me a hint on how I could do this?  (Or alternatively, another way to tweak a force-based graph drawing algorithm to minimize the number of times the lines cross?)  I'm just looking for a hint; no source code please.

In case anybody's interested, my [source code](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10645749/nodes-2012-02-18.zip) and a [youtube vid](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CFynirN0vPA) I made about it.

Comment: Have a look at NetBeans or similar tools which can optimize layout of graphs like class diagrams etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly include a term in your cost function that minimizes the number of edge crossings. For example, for every pair of edges that cross, you incur a fixed penalty or, if the edges are weighted, you incur a penalty that is the product of the two weights.